# Running multiple commands in the same cron job using Ansible

Tags: cron, ansible

I currently have a cronjob that creates a backup of a postgres db in ansible

```
- name: Create a cron job to export database.
  become_user: postgres
  cron:
    name: "Export database"
    minute: "*/2"
    job: "pg_dump -U postgres -W -F t db_name > db_backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).tar"
```

I want to run a `gsutil cp` command in the same job that then uploads this backup to a storage location in GCP.

I understand that with a cronjob you would simply separate the two jobs with `&&` however I'm not sure how this would work in ansible.

Any pointers would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you put in the `job` attribute will end up in the `crontab`. (You can check this with `crontab -l` on the machine).

So you can do everything in ansible, you could do on the `crontab` directly, including chaining multiple commands separated by `&&` or `;`.

If you have a very long line here, I'd suggest to write a script and have cron execute that for readability reasons.